# Azure App Config Error in Azure Portal, Not able to add configs

Tags: azure, config

I provisioned a Azure App Config , when I try to access it, I am getting this error

Can anyone help how to solve it?

[image]

Any Pointers will be helpful!

EDIT - 3/17

[image]

**UPDATE : EDIT - 3/25**

This is solved, looks like a proxy/firewall on my laptop was blocking it, network admin un-blocked it

Comment: Is the user you're signed into the portal with a member of the Global Administrator or Owner roles for this resource? Did this resolve after some period of time? From the error message, I'd think this was a transient problem.

Comment: I have "App Configuration Data " and "Contributor" Role

Answer (score 1):

- I am able  to access the Configuration explorer without any error.

[image]

- Your error says that there is some issue with the network/firewall/browser extensions.
- ***Try to  open https://yourstorename.azconfig.io/kv in the same browser that you're using to observe the error.***

  ***If you get a 401, that means there is no problem with the network. If you get other results, such as timeout, means your network can't reach the App Configuration service.***

[image]

- You can't connect to App config owing to network troubles . Please try a different machine/network/browser, disable vpn, check firewall rules to see if the problem goes away.

***When you use private endpoints for your App Configuration store, you can:***

Configure the firewall to prohibit any connections to App Configuration on the public endpoint to protect your application configuration details.

- Create a VNET, link it to a private endpoint, and approve it.

Please refer  [Using private endpoints for Azure App Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/concept-private-endpoint) for more information.

Comment: I am getting CORS error, I edited and attached the same

Answer (score 0):

Go to your App Configuration resource in the Azure Portal, then click on the Networking blade.

Please make sure that Public Access is set to Enabled. It sounds like you've got it set to Disabled.

[image: The Networking Blade]

If it's already set to Enabled, then I'd open a support ticket with Microsoft and share the CORS error that you've displayed above.

Comment: I already enabled, no luck :(, yes, I raised a ticket

Comment: I do think it's a problem on Azure's side. Please let us know what they tell you.